# ASP.NET - UserType-wise page access

Tags: asp.net

Suppose I have 3 kinds of users and their accessible pages in my ASP.net application are as follows:

```
(1) User Type-A {Default.aspx, a.aspx, b.aspx and c.aspx},

(2) User Type-B {Default.aspx, d.aspx, e.aspx and f.aspx},

(4) Admin {Default.aspx and g.aspx}.
```

Here `Default.aspx` is my Login-page.

I am using Membership Provider and Forms authentication technique.

Now I need to block access of one type of user to the pages assigned for other type users.

How should I configure my `Web.config` file?

and What kind of c# code should be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Role management in asp.net may help you in this case.  Please check this article.
You may have to customize this as per your specific requirement.  Hope this helps.

[Role Manager in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998314.aspx)

Each of User-Type will be associated with Roles.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar requirement, and make use of the [Patterns and Practices Web Client Software Factory](http://www.codeplex.com/websf). Basically it assists you in creating modules, and allowing you to specify per-page access levels in config based on Role / User details.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a try to use roleship provider and web.sitemap.