# asp.net's Obscure Role Provider

Tags: asp.net, roleprovider

Plz refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333508/asp-net-usertype-wise-page-access) previous post of mine.

I have studied asp.net's membership provider.

Now I need to study how to use asp.net's Role Provider facility in combination with Forms Authentication.

I did study MSDN's Role Provider topic. It was not helpful for beginners as usual.

I have also searched Google. That was also a failure.

Can anyone plz provide me with any web link that explain the Role Provider with a clear, complete and ready to run asp.net (C#) example?

Comment: Have you looked at the security series on asp.net http://www.asp.net/learn/security/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read more about entire forms authentication, membership ans roles at [ASP .Net Security](http://www.asp.net/learn/security/)