# ASP.NET Role, RolePrivider, ASP.net sql server setup wizard

Tags: asp.net, roleprovider

I am using asp.net forms authentication, membership provider and role provider.

You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372518/asp-net-role-provider-vs-membership-provider).

This post helped me to restrict access of the users to the specific areas of Web application according to their roles.

But the roles are hard-coded in the Web.config file.

I need to read the roles from the asp.net role provider database.

I want to use the database generated by this command:
[**`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regsql`**]

and the following tool:

[image]

and [**`aspnetdb`**] database.

And I want to use microsoft's framework and avoid my own customization as far as possible.

Plz tell me how can I generate authentication and authorization ticket. Better if you can show me some **C#** code.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: @Rex M, I have already created DB, written Web.config file and need some C# code to generate authentication ticket.

Comment: @JMSA the `;)` usually means it's a joke

Comment: I know. I am in a hurry at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already wired Authentication and Membership using SQL Server in your site it will be easy for you. Just follow these steps:

Create role store on sql server

```
   aspnet_regsql -S .\SQLExpress -E -A r

    -S specifies the server, which is (.\SQLExpress) in this example.
    -E specifies to use Windows authentication to connect to SQL Server.
    -A r specifies to add only the role provider feature.
```

Add connection string for role provider:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyLocalSQLServer"
       connectionString="Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;
      data source=.\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Add role manager:

```
<system.web>
  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySqlRoleProvider" >
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="MySqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="MyLocalSQLServer"
           applicationName="MyAppName"
           type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
</system.web>
```

Now you can use Role based stuff in your pages (supposing you have already enabled authentication [windows or forms])

Test ASPX:

```
    All Defined Roles: <asp:Lable id="lblAllRoles" runat="server" /><br/>
    Your Roles: <asp:label id="lblMyRoles" runat="server" /><br/>
```

Codebehind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //here we are supposing that user is already authenticated

        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

        //gets roles for currently authenticated user
        var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();            

        foreach (var v in roles)
            sb.Append(", " + v);

        lblMyRoles.Text = sb.ToString();
        sb.Remove(0,sb.Length);

        string [] allRoles = Roles.GetAllRoles();
        foreach(var v in allRoles)
           sb.Append(", " + v);

        lblAllRoles.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
```

Simillarly you can use `Role.IsUserInRole("ROLE_NAME")` to check if user is assigned particular role.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot, can you plz tell me, shoult I check the role by using Role.IsUserInRole("ROLE_NAME") in the page_load event? If yes, then can you tell me any other technique?

Comment: Say on your site there is a page that only the users in ADMIN role should access then you can utilize this method **Role.IsUserInRole("ADMIN")** in page_load event. If you don't want to test in **Page_Load** you can move it to **OnPreInit** and if user is not in role redirect to another page. You can also use **User.IsInRole** function also.

Comment: Then I can drop the roleship info from web.config file. Isn't it?

Comment: I mean, can I use any other technique than testing the Role in Page_Load, OnPreinit, etc? Any automated technique?

Comment: No you cannot. Then the role provider will not work. If you are going to use your custom classes to query database (aspnetdb) for roles assigned to user and manager roles then you can drop stuff from config file. **Automated** way is to define the roles allowed for different directories and files in web.config like: <location path="admin.aspx">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow roles="admin"/>
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard Login Usercontrols to authenticate users or do this manually, see [ASP.NET Role Provider vs Membership Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372518/asp-net-role-provider-vs-membership-provider/1372562#1372562) for code and explanation.